# How to add a blank line in the log file using log4net?

Tags: c#, winforms, log4net

I used RollingFileAppender. And I want add a blank line to the log when my program launches. How to do that? Thanks.

Edit:
OK, thanks for you all. Sorry for the confused question I asked.
Let me make some explanation.
I config the log4net as follows:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="MyFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="ClientLog.log" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss},%5p,%m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="GlobalUse" >
    <level value="Info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="MyFileAppender" />
  </logger>

</log4net>
```

and the log will be:

```
2010/03/27 13:55:27, INFO, Program start.
2010/03/27 13:55:29, INFO, Program end.
2010/03/27 13:56:30, INFO, Program start.
2010/03/27 13:56:32, INFO, Program end.
```

What i hope is make the log looks like this:

```
2010/03/27 13:55:27, INFO, Program start.
2010/03/27 13:55:29, INFO, Program end.

2010/03/27 13:56:30, INFO, Program start.
2010/03/27 13:56:32, INFO, Program end.

2010/03/27 13:57:30, INFO, Program start.
...
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: sorry, why do you want to add a white line? :-) And also.. your problem is how to log with log4net the white line or WHERE to put that log sentence?

Comment: You're right. My question shall be how to log with log4net the white line. Can you tell me how?  Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in header/footer feature (see http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#layout-header-xml-newlines )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a special appender. Here you have a configuration example

```
<log4net>
  ...
  <appender name="MyRollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\temp\mylog.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="MyLogger">
    <level value="Info" />
    <appender-ref ref="MyRollingLogFileAppender" />
  </logger>  
  ...
</log4net>
```

This configuration allows the insert of a WHITE LINE, COMPLETELY WHITE (<conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />)

And the code to log would be

`LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogger").Info("");`

A last comment: this allows you to do what I think you want but I wouldn't do it in my own development :-) if I misunderstood your question please let me know

**EDIT1** This appedender / logger is ADDED to your existing configuration. It would be ONLY used to generate the white line you need. For the rest of the logging you would use your previously existing logger / appender,

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But that will make insert a newline everytime when i log. I made some explanation to my question. You would have a look at that, if you still have interest in the question.

Answer (score 25):

The selected answer is MUCH more difficult than it needs to be.  I'm not sure if it didn't exist when the question was originally asked, but the correct way to do this is with a `<header>` or `<footer>` in the appender's layout.  Something like this:

```xml
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <footer value="&#13;&#10;" />
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

That will insert a blank line as a footer to each logging run.  More detail is here: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#layout-header-xml-newlines

Comment: Worked brilliantly for me. Agreed that this is much simpler than the accepted answer.

Comment: @Nick This does not seem to address the requirement in the original question. The requirement was to insert a blank line at the end of the program run. This solution inserts a blank line after **every** log entry.

Comment: @kannankeril I've used this precise configuration in a few programs for several years and I'm positive they only print the footer when the logging is ended (normally when the program terminates). Are you manually closing the stream?  Or maybe Log4net has changed how they handle footers (or has a bug) -- I've moved over to nLog so I can't say for certain.  However [the docs suggest it should still work](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Layout_DynamicPatternLayout_Footer.htm).

Comment: Still working as expected so log4net hasn't changed. I think your issue is related to your setup @kannankeril

Answer (score 7):

Log.Debug(Environment.Newline);

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I edited the question. That maybe more clear.
Your solution can add a newline indeed. But the last logline would be little strange.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
</layout>
```

with

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%message%newline%newline" />
</layout>
```

This will add two newlines at the end of file. First one will be there as a new Line , second one acts as a starting point of the next log.